# List supported authorisation mode in standard k8s & EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

While reading this blog-post https://raesene.github.io/blog/2023/04/08/lets-talk-about-kubelet-authorization/

Found that there are multiple authorisation modes supported, my understanding was ABAC & now RBAC.

Read that in kubelet config in certain config we have this flag `--authorization-mode=Node,RBAC`.

Wanted to understand there some `kubectl` command to find which all authorisation modes are present/supported ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using local cluster, to find out which authorization modes are supported in your Kubernetes cluster, you can use the `kubectl` command to retrieve this information. You can achieve this by checking the cluster configuration, specifically the `kube-apiserver` component.

Here's how you can do it:

```bash
kubectl describe pod kube-apiserver-<your-api-server-pod-name> -n kube-system
```

Replace `<your-api-server-pod-name>` with the actual name of your `kube-apiserver` pod in the `kube-system` namespace.

Look for the `--authorization-mode` flag in the output. This flag will specify which authorization modes are enabled in your cluster. It might look something like this:

```yaml
--authorization-mode=Node,RBAC
```

In the example above, both Node and RBAC authorization modes are enabled in the cluster. You can have different modes enabled based on your cluster configuration, and this command will provide you with the authoritative list of enabled authorization modes.